# Explicitly call java-html-sanitizer the way PrimeFaces does for its p:textEditor component

Tags: jsf, quill, html-sanitizing

While fighting for a good solution to an earlier question of mine:

[Add a custom button to the Quill's toolbar (and integrate it also on the PrimeFaces Text Editor)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894802/add-a-custom-button-to-the-quills-toolbar-and-integrate-it-also-on-the-primefa)

I found out that using directly Quill in my PrimeFaces application (and not the p:textEditor component) makes it much more easy to add a custom control to the Quill toolbar. An example implementation in a pure Java Script is found here:

[how to add css class to a quill selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247878/how-to-add-css-class-to-a-quill-selection)

Integrating the above Code in a PrimeFaces application is relatively easy. However, what I miss is how to correctly apply the java-html-sanitizer to the content of the Quill Editor, which  I receive now in the backing bean of my PrimeFaces application. Indeed there are examples of usage here:

https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md

but I want to call the java-html-sanitizer in exactly the same way as PrimeFaces does for its p:textEditor component

Could somebody help me?

Comment: If you are using quill directly, this question is in no way PrimeFaces related. And the content is send to a JSF application...

Comment: @Kukeltje yep, you are right. But I would like to know how p:texteditor calls the sanitezer, (what option(s), policy, etc) unless this is somehow secret.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/texteditor/TextEditorRenderer.java but there is only a check inside wheter sanitezr is available (at the end of the class)

Comment: Then look better, it is in that source file... `ctrl+f sani` will show it... I could write an answer but this is too easy...

Comment: Oh and the way PF uses it is 100% like in the examples in the HTMLSanitizer examples...

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you, I somehow completely missed this.

Comment: @Kukeltje By the way, I would like to write down what  I found out on integrating Quill with Primefaces one day, when I am ready and have time. It could be a good idea that some experienced developer, like you, revise it and then update the PrimeFaces documentation. To me, it is very unpleasant (and misleading), that the documentation on p:textEditor does not explicitly mention adding custom buttons / handlers, but only gives a vague example on using a SUBSET of the already existing Quill butttons (so that one cannot directly infer whether and how adding custom buttons is supported)